# BG Won't Appear in IE, but works in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Below are screenshots of the background in IE and Firefox. Ignore the error message on the first screenshot. All that has been fixed and my site is centered. However, the background image isn't appearing for some reason.

Here is a screenshot in IE - http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/856/d47x.jpg

Here is what it should look like - http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/838/cxao.jpg

The code I have for the background is provided here.  Thank you in advanced for all your help.

```
   body
    {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-image: url("./web_elements/bg.png"), url("./web_elements/tex2.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat,repeat;
        background-position:top center,0 0;
    }
```

I also changed my javascript code to get rid of the error on the first screenshot. But the BG still causes an issue.

```
function resizePage() {

    var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    var objMainBlock = document.getElementById('MainBlock');
    var objPad = width > 1024 ? (width - 1024) / 2 : 0;

    objMainBlock.style.width = "1024px";
    objMainBlock.style.marginLeft = objPad + "px";
}
```

Comment: Wich version of IE ? http://caniuse.com/multibackgrounds

Comment: The IE version I currently have that this workstation is IE Version 9.

Comment: Looks like a path error.

Comment: Is the PNG a real PNG? IE doesn't like PNG's that aren't pngs

Comment: I created that background in photoshop. I tried .jpg, no luck. And it isn't a path error Paulie_D because it works in chrome and firefox. And ignore the message on the screenshot in IE, it was a different issue that's already resolved.

Comment: Nevermind I fixed my own problem. In developer tools, the document mode was set to IE 7.. I am unsure but its set to that by default.. either way I know it works for IE9 as it should. Thanks for your input anyway

Comment: [Check your Compatibility View settings](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2009/05/internet-explorer-8-intranet.html) and make sure "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" is unchecked.  And, of course, make sure the first line of html is `<!doctype html>`.

Comment: Check that you have your X_UA-Compatible set to edge. This is either a META tag or an HTTP header.